# Adding a Python handler in suPHP?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, suphp

I have the PHP handler working perfectly fine, but one of my friends would like to use Python as well. I have Python installed on my server at `/usr/bin/python2` (for Python2) as well as `/usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3` (for Python3). He prefers Python2 so I was just going to have .py files use the Python2 binary. Anyways, after setting it up in the Apache config and suPHP config, it keeps giving me the following error:

```
SecurityException in Application.cpp:511: Unknown Interpreter: python:/usr/bin/python2
Premature end of script headers: test.py
```

The relevant lines from httpd.conf:

```
AddType text/x-python .py
suPHP_AddHandler text/x-python .py
```

and under the `[handlers]` section of suphp.conf:

```
text/x-python="python:/usr/bin/python2"
```

What do I need to do in order to get Python working via suPHP, if it's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suPHP is specifically designed for PHP; you'll need to use [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html), which is part of Apache and simple to use. As long as the python scripts are normally executable as CGIs, it should work fine.